# Fallback function in solidity

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

Tried to create a simple wallet with a fallback function but still
VM error: revert. Note: The constructor should be payable if you send value. Why?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
contract MyWallet
  {
      struct account
       {
        uint balance;
        uint dailyLimit;
       }

      mapping (address =>account) _accounts;
      //created  this fallback payable function
    function () payable {
         _accounts[msg.sender].balance+=msg.value;
       }  

      //to get balance
    function getBalance() returns (uint){
        return _accounts[msg.sender].balance;
       }

 }
```

Comment: You should explain your question in more detail, to allow other users to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You get this error because you're trying to call an explicit function that isn't payable. The error message will occur if you send ether during deployment and there is no `payable` on the contstructor, or if you initiate a transaction through a defined function that isn't marked as `payable`. To trigger the fallback function, you would send a transaction in which the `data` field (which describes what will be invoked) is empty.